# Objective-C detect every multitouch

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, touch, multi-touch

I am working on a game using `cocos2d`, and I want to call a method every time there is more than one touch detected, and call another method when the `multitouch` becomes `single touch` or no touch.

The game has multiple `UIGestureRecognizers` listening, so I want to handle these events in one place, rather than adding into all of their selectors checks for `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` to track the changes in number of touches.

Any suggestions?

Comment: just check the count of the NSSet you receive in touchesBegan

Comment: and you can achieve it without using UIGestureRecognizer. actually it is even better in cocos2d project.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D But I can be in the middle of a long press with one finger when another finger touches screen; touchesBegan only shows 1 touch in the NSSet for this case.

Comment: That's to be expected because the gesture recognizer "captures" the touches it "recognizes". If that's a problem you'd have to write your own gesture recognizer or subclass the existing one so that touches are forwarded regardless.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I see. So if I want to long press with one finger, add one more finger to long press and pinch at the same time, let go of the finger pinching, and add the same finger again to long press and swipe at the same time, I will need to implement my own gesture recognizer or subclass an existing one as well?

Comment: err, honestly I think you need to rethink your design. Are you aiming to break the user's fingers? Keep it simple. But generally if you want to mix various gesture recognizers at the least you'll have to set which cancels whose touches.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Haha I am working on a platformer, and each of those gestures affects the character in some way. Those behaviors are not necessary, but I wanted to support them in case the player tries something fancy (to complete a level faster, for example).